# Kendo TreeList Locked Column Isn't Working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treelist

I have a Kendo TreeList. I'm trying to lock the first column like this:

```
columns: [
                { field: "field1", title: "Field 1", locked: true },
                { field: "field2", title: "Field 2" }
]
```

With the locked:true there, however, my TreeList doesn't even load. What might I be missing?

Comment: Syntax looks coorect. Are you sure that if you remove only _locked: true_ from the code, that it starts work? It looks like problem can be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, removing only locked: true causes the TreeList to not render

Answer (score 1):

It seems you must specify the field widths in order for column locking to work. In addition, the columns to the right of the locked column(s) must fill up enough width to cause the scrolling to engage.

```
columns: [
                { field: "field1", title: "Field 1", locked: true, width:200 },
                { field: "field2", title: "Field 2", width: 1000 }
]
```